# Helm chart propagate values from main chart to subcharts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a chart with several subcharts that should all use the same annotations as the main chart and I only want to define said annotations once in my main `values.yaml`. As far as I understood, functions defined in the `_helpers.tbl` are also available for the subcharts to use. Though, I cannot get my setup to propagate my annotation into the subcharts.

Here are the relevant snippets:

```
# Source: mainchart/values.yaml
serviceAnnotations: 
  propagated: "true"
...


---
# Source: mainchart/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations: 
  {{- include "automate.annotations" . | nindent 4 }}
...


---
# Source: mainchart/templates/_helpers.tbl
{{/*
Global annotations
*/}}
{{- define "automate.annotations" -}}
{{- with .Values.serviceAnnotations }}
  {{- toYaml . }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
...


---
# Source: mainchart/charts/subchart/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations: 
  {{- include "automate.annotations" . | nindent 4 }}
...
```

Checking the populated charts with:

```
helm install mainchart mainchart/ --dry-run
```

---

EDIT:

I could get a similar approach to work by integrating the main function into the subchart´s `_helper.tbl`. It does not work for the above mentioned use case, though.

```
# Source: mainchart/templates/_helpers.tbl
{{- define "automate.labels" -}}
{{- if .Values.DevopsRunId }}
devopsPipeline: {{ .Values.DevopsRunId }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
...


---
# Source: mainchart/charts/subchart/templates/_helpers.tbl
{{- define "subchart.labels" -}}
helm.sh/chart: {{ include "subchart.chart" . }}
{{ include "subchart.selectorLabels" . }}
{{ include "automate.labels" . }}
{{- end }}
```

This in fact resulted in propagated labels to the subchart.

Answer (score 0):

When you `define` a helper template, it takes a single parameter, much like a function in other programming languages.  Within the template code `.` refers to the template parameter, and `.Values` is a field named `Values` within that template parameter.

The important consequence of this is that a `define`d template does not "capture" the context where it's defined.  You call (`include`) the template twice from two different places.  In both you pass `.` as the parameter.  In the main chart, `.` is the top-level Helm object, but in the sub-chart, it's already been scoped to include only the sub-chart's values; you cannot get back to the top-level values, even if you're calling a template defined in the top-level chart.

The one mechanism Helm does give you here is [global chart values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#global-chart-values): `.Values.global` is propagated into all of the subcharts unchanged.  If you use this in the helper

```
{{- define "automate.annotations" -}}
{{- toYaml .Values.global.serviceAnnotations }}
{{- end }}
```

and move the definitions in your main `values.yaml` file

```yaml
# Source: mainchart/values.yaml
global:
  serviceAnnotations: 
    propagated: "true"
```

it will have the effect you want.

Comment: make sense, I could get a similar use case to work by including the main function into the subchart´s _helpers.tbl (see my edits). Though, it does not work it this case. Will do the global approach, thanks for the comprehensive answer